# Phone Bluetooth extender

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, telephone

I'm looking for a extender/increase in my bluetooth range on my phone, can it really be we don't have any thing like that, or can I just take my phone apart and solder a 2,4ghz antenna to it?

Comment: Do you really think you phone maker designed a phone capable of better BT range, but just screwed up the antenna part?

Comment: Doing so would probably violate the FCC specs.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is not like WiFi where you can extend the range by adding an access point. Bluetooth is not designed for that.

You can also forget about "soldering a 2.4 GHz antenna to your phone",  2.4 GHz is RF, you can easily screw it up (and with your lack of knowledge you will) and make things worse.

The antenna is also not the limiting factor. Bluetooth is for short range. If you need long range, use something else.